# Displaying axis values with matlab

Tags: image, matlab, plot

I am displaying an image:

```
% Load some image:
data = imread(srcPath);

% display the image:
figure;
imshow(data);
axis image;
```

Is there anyway to get some example values near the axis?

Ignore the messagebox:

[image]

Basically this is the output using

```
imagesc(data);
```

But I wouldn't use imagesc just to display axis like that

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by, "Is there anyway to get some values near the axis?"

Comment: Please look at the image in my question. I just want to display 100 - 200 - 300 etc

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "But I wouldn't use imagesc just to display axis like that"?

Comment: Imagesc is used when you need to scale the image. I don't need to scale it. I just need to show it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is done through the attributes `xtick` for horizontal axis and `ytick` for vertical axis. You have to use the `set(gca, ...)` syntax to do it. There are some good examples in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-15HXQ/).